# Call Javascript from Java

Tags: java, javascript, url, web, download

I'm downloading a search result from a [website](http://www.geocaching.com/seek/nearest.aspx?country_id=79&as=1&ex=0) using java which works great for the first page.

```
URL url = new URL(
        "http://www.geocaching.com/seek/nearest.aspx?country_id=79&as=1&ex=0");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        url.openStream()));

String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
in.close();
```

But how could I get the second page of the result? The link to the second page uses a javascript call `javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentBody$pgrBottom$lbGoToPage_2','')`, which calls this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
  theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
  if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
      theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
      theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
      theForm.submit();
  }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

I think, i need to call the function from my java programm to get the second page, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell you want to execute __doPostBack(...) as if it were on a web page executing in a browser. I can't see how you could do that programmatically using Java. If I were you I would try and manually create the post request that the Javascript is invoking (maybe using something like [this](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d4e191)). I know its not ideal because if the page changes your application wont work anymore but its the only reasonable solution I can think of.

Can I ask what exactly you are trying to achieve? Would something like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) help?

Comment: I am trying to download all the data for later processing. I think Selenium wouldn't help.

Comment: @multiholle You could use Selenium to walk through the pages you were interested in and save the relevant content of each page to a file which could then be processed at another time.

Comment: @multiholle You should probably do the post manually then. Check out the link I mentioned.

Comment: How do I get the content of the post message I have to send?

Comment: Your going to have to scan the page and hard code any forum variables that need to be added. Obviously this is an extremely fragile approach but what you are trying to do is inherently fragile anyway. I guess the most robust way would be to do what Chris Knight suggested but it adds a lot of complexity.

Answer (score 1):

check out `javax.script.ScriptEngine` and `javax.script.ScriptEngineManager` and other stuff in the package:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
engine.eval(...);
```

Comment: This works great for evaluating javascript code in java, but how do I get the connection to the website. The function `__doPostBack(...)` works only in context of the website.

Comment: @multiholle You should check what is called in `theForm.submit();`. Maybe you won't need to run java script at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Direct Web Remoting (DWR). This engine supports calling java methods from JavaScript and vice versa. Find more info at  http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html